# Can't figure out why this code runs perfect for input of 3 and breaks on 5. {homework}

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

When I input 3 into the below code it prints perfectly in the shape I need. But when the input is > 3 the code seems to break as you can see in the pictures below. I think I've probably just been staring at this for too long and can't find the obvious stupid error. I'm somewhat new to python so please go easy.

```
size = int(input("Size: "))

def middle1():
    count_middle1 = 0
    size_m1 = (size + 1)
    mid_1 = 1
    mid_2 = 1
    dots_a = 2
    bslsh = "\\"
    fslsh = "/"    
    while (count_middle1 != size):
        print("|"+("."*dots_a)+((fslsh+bslsh)*mid_1)+("."*size_m1)+((fslsh+bslsh)*mid_2)+("."*dots_a)+"|")
        mid_1+=1
        mid_2+=1        
        count_middle1+=1
        dots_a-=1
        size_m1-=2
middle1()
```

[Input == 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQI3k.png)

[Input == 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjReC.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: With Python27 It works well with both the inputs. I just changed `size = int(raw_input(""))`

Comment: you really should pass size to the function/method `def middle1(size)`

Comment: @saurabhbaid I'm sorry I should have specified this was done in 3.5.2

Comment: @DanielLee I'm calling the function at the end but it would not let me add it into the code on here for some odd reason.

Comment: I just checked on the online interpreter of python3. Same code works well.
https://repl.it/DfwL/0

Comment: Sorry may bad, I though its a compile error, but its rather and logical error.

Comment: @saurabhbaid Thats interesting I get the same output on that link as my above picture for input of 5

Comment: can you tell what exactly do you want your to be.

Comment: well, one problem is your dots_a, this is hard coded and should change depending on the length of your input (if I understand your goal correctly)

Comment: @bck- check this if this is what you want https://repl.it/DfwL/1

Comment: @Philipp nice catch so I change the dots_a variable to size and now its close but the last line is printing one extra set of forward and back slashes. so one more logical error it seems.

Comment: @saurabhbaid Thats close but if you see when the input is > 3 it is not actually finishing the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want two trees next to each other.

```
|........./\................../\.........|
|......../\/\................/\/\........|
|......./\/\/\............../\/\/\.......|
|....../\/\/\/\............/\/\/\/\......|
|...../\/\/\/\/\........../\/\/\/\/\.....|
|..../\/\/\/\/\/\......../\/\/\/\/\/\....|
|.../\/\/\/\/\/\/\....../\/\/\/\/\/\/\...|
|../\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\..../\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\../\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\.|
|/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\|
```

There is two problems, one that I mentioned in the comments which is the `dots_a`. The second problem is your `size_m1`. Try to think what you need to change it to so it works for any `size`.

Comment: yup that was it. Its always the multiply that gets me. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Good on you finding the solution with just the hint. Didn't want to spoil it right away. Much more rewarding this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you.

```
def middle1(size):
    count_middle1 = 0
    size_m1 = (size * 2)
    mid_1 = 1
    mid_2 = 1
    dots_a = int(size_m1 / 2)
    bslsh = "\\"
    fslsh = "/"    
    while (count_middle1 != size):
        print("|"+("."*dots_a)+((fslsh+bslsh)*mid_1)+("."*size_m1)+((fslsh+bslsh)*mid_2)+("."*dots_a)+"|")
        mid_1+=1
        mid_2+=1        
        count_middle1+=1
        dots_a-=1
        size_m1-=2
    print("\n")
```

And this will give you output

```
middle1(2)
middle1(3)
middle1(4)
middle1(5)
|../\..../\..|
|./\/\../\/\.|


|.../\....../\...|
|../\/\..../\/\..|
|./\/\/\../\/\/\.|


|..../\......../\....|
|.../\/\....../\/\...|
|../\/\/\..../\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\../\/\/\/\.|


|...../\........../\.....|
|..../\/\......../\/\....|
|.../\/\/\....../\/\/\...|
|../\/\/\/\..../\/\/\/\..|
|./\/\/\/\/\../\/\/\/\/\.|
```

Comment: @bck if you want to remove extra dot you could do
`'dots_a = int(size_m1 / 2) - 1`

Comment: that worked also. Thank you for all of your help. Apparently, multiplication is too hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for any input

```
size = int(input("Size: "))

def middle1():
    count_middle1 = 0
    size_m1 = (size - 1)*2
    mid_1 = 2
    mid_2 = 2
    dots_a = size-1
    bslsh = "\\"
    fslsh = "/"
    while (count_middle1 < size):
        print("|"+("."*(dots_a))+((fslsh+bslsh)*(mid_1-1))+("."*size_m1)+((fslsh+bslsh)*(mid_2-1))+("."*(dots_a))+"|")
        mid_1+=1
        mid_2+=1
        count_middle1+=1
        dots_a-=1
        size_m1-=2
middle1()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up using.